# Issue when appending a CTFrame to a Swift Array

Tags: swift, core-text

I have a CoreText that works in Objective-C and the migration to Swift is driving me nuts.

This is the (simplified) code:

```
var ctFramesArray: Array<CTFrame> = CTFrame[]()

ctFramesArray.append(ctFrame)
```

The `ctFrame` is a valid object. I can inspect it with the debugger, println() it, and the project runs fine rendering the CoreText columns properly.

The `ctFramesArray` reports zero objects after being created and before appending the first `ctFrame` object.

But I have a run time error (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS) when trying to append the `ctFrame` to the Array.

It seems that is is an assertion failure, but I can´t figure out what it is

**UPDATE:**

This behaviour is strange

I have the following cases:

```
    var ctFramesArray: Array<CTFrame> = Array<CTFrame>()
    ctFramesArray.append(ctFrame)
    println(ctFramesArray.count)
```

The `ctFramesArray.append(ctFrame)` line works fine when the `ctFramesArray` is local (within the function), but if it is a global variable, I get the run time `EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error.

I tested this using an array of strings as follows and it works with the array being declared locally or globally.  It seems that the issue is related to the `CTFrame` type (the ctFrame object is valid and the frames are rendered correctly)

```
    var stringsArray: Array<String> = Array<String>()
    stringsArray.append("One")
    println(stringsArray.count)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to the problem

If the global variable `ctFramesArray` is defined "globally" as an array of `CTFrame` objects, then we get the run time error.  But if the array is defined as an array of `AnyObject`, as follows, then the issue is fixed:

```
var ctFramesArray: Array<AnyObject> = Array<AnyObject>()
```

There seems to be an issue with the `AnyObject` compatibility in the `CTFrame` object.

The puzzling part is still the fact that with the array declared locally as Array, the declaration works fine

... e

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue related to the ARC ref count for the CTFrame.  How did you obtain ctFrame? I suspect ctFrame has a shorter lifetime than ctFramesArray and that will cause a crash.

Comment: user3670399.  I doubt it is a life-cycle issue with the ctFrame object, given that (i) The ctFrame objects are created within the same function, using: let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(textPosition, 0), path, nil);    (ii)  I can println(ctFrame) right before trying to add it to the array.    (iii).   the array.append(ctFrame) works is the array is declared within the same function (not global).   This is really strange