# Issue with the CTFrame compatibility with AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, core-text

I found an issue when adding a CTFrame object to a global Array (the question is here: 
[Issue when appending a CTFrame to a Swift Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442722/issue-when-appending-a-ctframe-to-a-swift-array)) and as I dig dipper, it seems to be an issue with the `AnyObject` compatibility of the `CTFrame` Opaque Type

Considering the following:

```
var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddRect(path, nil, self.view.frame)
let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(NSAttributedString())
let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil);

var ctFramesArray = Array<CTFrame>() // CTFrame type declaration works fine
ctFramesArray.append(ctFrame) // ctFrame is valid can be added to a local array

let object: AnyObject = ctFrame
let frame: CTFrame = object as CTFrame // This line generates the linker error
```

I create a simple `CTFrame` object with an empty attrString (the result is the same with a complex attrString). The object is valid, I can `println()` it, and it can be added to a locally declared array.  But if I convert the `CTFrame` object to `AnyObject` and try to create a new `CTFrame` object from the AnyObject object, the compiler complains and suggests adding as CTFrame (forced down casting).

The problem with this, is that the project won´t compile, given that Xcode reports an `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTFrame", referenced from:,` that is weird, given that the CoreText framework is added, and the CTFrame type is used, (e.g. when declaring the Array, and when rendering the CTFrames).

May I be missing something?

..e

Comment: Any luck yet?  I am stuck on this as well.

Comment: Nop. For some reason I can´t add CTFrames to an Array that is local. Trying to add CTFrames to a global array or passing the an Array with CTFrames as argument between functions or classes crashes.  I can manage it to compile and run if everything is AnyObject, but nothing will draw, given that the render in DrawRect needs to convert to CTFrame... Frustrating

Comment: Sorry... I can add the CTFrames to a local Array. This fails when adding the CTFrame to a global Array